# Difference between defaultValue and autoValue in Autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm working on a project which I start with using autoValue as

`Programs.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
      return this.userId
    },
    optional: true,
     autoform: {
       type: 'hidden'
     }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created At",
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      type: 'hidden'
    }
  }
}));`

everything works find until I need to update the information by other users, let's say admin, Programs.update or Programs.insert methods will change the email field.

I tried to use defaultValue for createdBy field but

`defaultValue: this.userId`

return me null

and i'm not allowed to use

`defaultValue: Meteor.userId()`

Can anyone explain the difference? I tried use function() {return this.userId} for defaultValue which still got no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultValue` is used by simple-schema for defining default value. There are some quirks so read the docs: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#defaultvalue

Think of when the code is ran and you will understand why you can't use `Meteor.userId()` or `this.userId` for `defaultValue`. The schema is ran once at startup.

What allows `autoValue` to work is that it returns a function. The function is ran during db updates/inserts. Read over the docs to fully understand it: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue

Now, if I understand your question properly, you have issues with `autoValue` when an admin comes along and modifies the document? Causing the `createdBy` to be set to the admin's id? To solve something like that, you just need to be more specific with your `autoValue` function.

See if this code helps guide you in the proper direction:

```
Programs.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return this.userId;
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return { $setOnInsert: this.userId };
      }

      this.unset(); // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      return undefined;
    },
    optional: true,
     autoform: {
       type: 'hidden'
     }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Created At',
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      type: 'hidden'
    },
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return { $setOnInsert: new Date() };
      }

      this.unset(); // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      return undefined;
    },
  }
}));
```

Comment: just a follow up question, I find out that, if I also set the autovalue field to hidden, I can't make modification on client side. I guess it got to be related to undefined input value during update, but I haven't got into it

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The client is inherently untrustworthy but be aware of the `clean` https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#cleaning-data method if you want to force autoValue calculations

Answer (score 0):

You should try this snippet,

```
new SimpleSchema({
   // ...
   createdBy: {
      autoValue() {
         return Meteor.userdId();
      }
   }
   // ...
})
```

Now the explanation, Your problem is more likely related with the `this` binding, this.userId, was called from SimpleSchema context in this way this does not have any `userId()` method, you should use the full namespace in this case `Meteor.userId()`;

A very cool explanation on `this` binding I recommend you to read
[This binding](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)